# ISTool command line problems

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

I am trying create installation file for my projects.
I am using command line so I created bat file "create_setup.bat". From this file I am trying to compile Inno Setup script "my_project_setup.iss":
"ISTool.exe" -compile "Subfolder1\Subfolder2\my_project_setup.iss". 
Important: "create_setup.bat" - located at the folder "WorkFolder" and Inno Setup script "my_project_setup.iss" located at the folder "WorkFolder\Subfolder1\Subfolder2".
But I don't have any good results, no installation file.
However if I running "create_setup.bat" from the same folder as script "my_project_setup.iss" located it's work correct (of course path at the file create_setup.bat to the script my_project_setup.iss was changed).
At the script "my_project_setup.iss" I have tried to change Inno Setup property "OutputDir"  but it's not help.
Inno Setup property "Source" I have not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your script so that you CD to the subfolders before calling ISTool.exe?

```
PUSHD "Subfolder1\Subfolder2"
ISTool.exe -compile my_project_setup.iss
POPD
```

Try that and see if it works better, it could have something to do with any relative paths you might have inside of your .iss file.